# Плавное изменение скорости анимации

Tags: javascript, css, анимация, frontend, css-animation

У меня есть элемент который анимируется с помощью `transition: transform 20s linear`. Т.е. он анимируется изначально равномерно.

По первому клику пользователя включается анимация и я задаю через js: `transform: translate(-900px)` и блок начинает двигаться влево. Потом, до окончания анимации, пользователь выбирает на сколько ещё прокрутить анимацию (N пикселей) и с этого момента анимация должна прокрутиться ещё N пикселей, но уже с замедлением. Т.е. я через js меняю анимацию на `transition: transform ?s ease-out` и `transform: translate(-Npx)`.

Но я не знаю сколько для этой анимации поставить секунд, что бы начальная скорость второй анимации равнялась бы скорости первой. Т.е. когда анимация начинала бы останавливаться она бы делала это без рывка. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это можно рассчитать?

Comment: Посчитать приращение длительности, без знания интервала обновления координат при анимации - невозможно. А если интервал непостоянный, то невозможно вдвойне :)

Comment: Суть в том, что для получения этого приращения, нужно посчитать  сумму y-координат (по кривой Безье) на оставшемся отрезке пути движения. И для получения этой суммы, нужно знать количество оставшихся кадров анимации...

Comment: Похоже, я был неправ насчет невозможности - посмотрите мой ответ. Вроде работает :) но проверял только на мобиле, где и писал код...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я попробовал решить просто добавлением длительности transition, с зависимостью от текущей Y-координаты на кривой Безье, задающей динамику ease-out'a.

Выстрадал формулу `newDuration = currentDuration + currentDuration * (1 + bezierCoordY(1 - position))`
, где `position` - текущая позиция на отрезке [`исходная_позиция`..`финишная_позиция`]. Естественно, приведенная к диапазону 0..1

Под спойлером - то, что получилось.

```js
const DURATION = 3;  // длительность transition

let $d = document, 
    block  = $d.getElementById('block'), 
    block2 = $d.getElementById('block2'), 
    line   = $d.getElementById('line'), 
    btns   = $d.getElementsByTagName('button'),
    x1 = block.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
    x2 = ($d.body.scrollWidth - 50) / 2 - 4; 

for (let btn of btns)
  btn.addEventListener('click', onBtnClick); 
updateLine(); 
requestAnimationFrame(updateTxt); 
console.log('Верхний едва видимый блок - для сравнения: он всегда движется линейно');

function onBtnClick() {
  let cl = block.classList; 
  switch (this.id) {
    case 'lnr':
      block.style.transition = `transform ${DURATION}s linear`;  
      incTransX(x2);
      block2.style.transition = `transform ${DURATION * 2}s linear`;
      block2.style.transform = `translateX(${x2 * 2}px)`;
      this.style.display = 'none'; 
      $d.getElementById('sdn').style.display = 'inline-block'; 
      break; 
    case 'sdn':
      incTransX(x2);
      changeTimingFunc('ease-out'); 
      this.style.display = 'none'; 
      break; 
    case 'clr': 
      block.style = null; 
      block2.style = null; 
      $d.getElementById('lnr').style.display = 'inline-block'; 
      $d.getElementById('sdn').style.display = 'none'; 
  }
  updateLine(); 
}

// для изменения параметров, необходимо остановить текущую анимацию - изменение "на лету" не работает 
function changeTimingFunc(tfunc) {
  let x2 = getTransX(), 
      xc = block.getBoundingClientRect().left, 
      t  = xc / x2,  // позиция в диапазоне 0..1
      nd = DURATION + DURATION * (1 + bezierCoordY(1 - t));  // новая длительность, с учетом Y-позиции на кривой Безье ease-out'a
  block.style.transform = `translateX(${xc}px)`;
  block.style.transitionTimingFunction = 'ease-out'; //'cubic-bezier(0, 0, 0.58, 1)'; 
  block.style.transitionDuration = nd + 's'; 
  setTimeout(() => {  // без этой задержки не сработает - видимо, у движка браузера есть интервал обновления параметров анимации (?)
    block.style.transform = `translateX(${x2}px)`;
    updateLine(); 
  }, 0); // минимально возможная задержка 
}

function bezierCoordY(t, p0 = 0, p1 = 0, p2 = 0.58, p3 = 1) {
  return Math.pow(1 - t, 3) * p0 +
    3 * Math.pow(1 - t, 2) * t * p1 +
    3 * (1 - t) * Math.pow(t, 2) * p2 +
    Math.pow(t, 3) * p3;
}

function updateLine() {
  line.style.width = getTransX() + block.offsetWidth + 'px'; 
}

function updateTxt() {
  let x = block.getBoundingClientRect().left; 
  block.textContent = (x / getTransX()).toFixed(4);
  requestAnimationFrame(updateTxt);  
}

function incTransX(value) {
  block.style.transform = `translateX(${getTransX() + value}px)`;  
}

function getTransX() {
  let x = block.style.transform.match(/\(([-\d]+)/i); 
  return x ? +x[1] : 0;
}
```

```css
html, 
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.block {
  width: 54px; height: 20px; 
  margin-top: 3px; 
  background-color: #4a4; 
  font: 12px monospace; color: #fff; 
  text-align: center; line-height: 20px; 
  transition: transform 0s; 
}

#block2 {
  margin-top: 30px; 
  background-color: #ccc4; 
}

#line {
  position: relative; 
  height: 1px; 
  background-color: #d44; 
  margin: 3px 0 30px 0; 
}
#line:after {
  content: 'длина пути'; 
  position: absolute; top: 1px; left: 3px; 
  font: 9px sans-serif; color: #d44; 
}

button {
  margin: 0 10px; padding: 8px 20px;
  border: 0;
  background-color: #29a; 
  box-shadow: 0 2px 8px -2px #0007;  
  font: 14px sans-serif; color: #fff; 
  text-transform: uppercase; 
}

#sdn {
  display: none;
  background-color: #24a; 
}
```

```html
<div id="block2" class="block"></div>
<div id="block" class="block"></div>
<div id="line"></div>
<button id="clr"><<<</button>
<button id="lnr">начать движение линейно</button>
<button id="sdn">добавление пути и ease-out</button>
```

В мобильном браузере, при добавлении пути есть мелкая задержка в долю секунды. Думаю, это от таймера... но не нашел способа, как без него изменять параметры перехода (если Вы знаете такой способ - пожалуйста, напишите его в коммент).

Comment: Спасибо. попробую применить.